# Iterate through statically created controls in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I'm trying to iterate forms in wpf but seems that

```
foreach (Control x in this.Controls) 
 { 
    if (x is TextBox) 
    {    
      do something
    } 
 }
```

is not working! compiler doesn't recognize this.controls 
....seems there is a difference in wpf but I don't what code should I use instead! 
Edit: I don't wanna use FindVisualChildren

Comment: and has more shortcut answers so This is not Duplicate :)
is there any way to get it out of this dupicated error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
        foreach (var control in MyGrid.Children.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
                //do something
        }
```

You cannot iterate through all your controls in a Window. You need to be more specific. Please note that this will only get direct children and not children of children

```
<Window>
   <Grid x:Name="MyGrid>
     <Button/>
     <TextBox/>
     <Label/>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```